# Can I shrink flexbox items into same size when flex items are bigger than the flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I expect that when flex items' total size is smaller than flex container, flex items should occupy respective space; and when flex items' total size is bigger than flex container, flex items should divide container's space equally.

Therefore, I set flex-grow to 0 and flex-shrink to 1. To make flex items shrink smaller than their min-content, I set min-height as 0.
But no matter how I set flex items' flex-basis property, I cannot get the desired style.

When flex items' total size is less than flex container's, example 1 of the right part of [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMD9E.png) is expected. When flex items' total size is more than flex container's, example 2 of the left part of [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtbVT.png) is expected.

```css
.flex-container {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #dadfe3;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 20px;
  max-height: 50%;
}

.flex-item div {
  margin: 4px 0;
  background-color: #f0f9ff;
  color: #2f88ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>Example 1</h2>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 1">
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 2</div>
      <div>item content 2</div>
      <div>item content 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2>Example 2</h2>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 1">
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 2</div>
      <div>item content 3</div>
      <div>item content 4</div>
      <div>item content 5</div>
      <div>item content 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 2">
      <div>item 1</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 3</div>
      <div>item 4</div>
      <div>item 5</div>
      <div>item 6</div>
      <div>item 7</div>
      <div>item 8</div>
      <div>item 9</div>
      <div>item 10</div>
      <div>item 11</div>
      <div>item 12</div>
      <div>item 13</div>
      <div>item 14</div>
      <div>item 15</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the desired style ? What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: I add a image to supplyment the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `display: grid` instead of `display: flex` to achieve this. Here is an example:

```css
.flex-container {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(minmax(0, auto), 50%));
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #dadfe3;
}

.flex-item {
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.flex-item div {
  margin: 4px 0;
  background-color: #f0f9ff;
  color: #2f88ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 1">
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 2</div>
      <div>item content 3</div>
      <div>item content 4</div>
      <div>item content 5</div>
      <div>item content 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 2">
      <div>item 1</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 3</div>
      <div>item 4</div>
      <div>item 5</div>
      <div>item 6</div>
      <div>item 7</div>
      <div>item 8</div>
      <div>item 9</div>
      <div>item 10</div>
      <div>item 11</div>
      <div>item 12</div>
      <div>item 13</div>
      <div>item 14</div>
      <div>item 15</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems you have changed your mind since asking the question and the requirements are now slightly different.

> It's better to move all the blank to bottom rather than divide them into two parts equally - @pIckedrAin

I will keep the answer above despite of this because it answers the original question and may help others with a similar problem in the future.

This is the adjustment you suggested due to your new requirements:

```css
.flex-container {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: grid;
  align-content: start;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #dadfe3;
}

.flex-item {
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.flex-item div {
  margin: 4px 0;
  background-color: #f0f9ff;
  color: #2f88ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 1">
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 2</div>
      <div>item content 3</div>
      <div>item content 4</div>
      <div>item content 5</div>
      <div>item content 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 2">
      <div>item 1</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 3</div>
      <div>item 4</div>
      <div>item 5</div>
      <div>item 6</div>
      <div>item 7</div>
      <div>item 8</div>
      <div>item 9</div>
      <div>item 10</div>
      <div>item 11</div>
      <div>item 12</div>
      <div>item 13</div>
      <div>item 14</div>
      <div>item 15</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

However, I think with your new requirements you do not need the grid layout any more. That was only needed to provide equal space for the items in case the containers height is smaller then the height of its content.

Here is the simple flex-box version:

```css
.flex-container {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #dadfe3;
}

.flex-item {
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.flex-item div {
  margin: 4px 0;
  background-color: #f0f9ff;
  color: #2f88ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 1">
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 2</div>
      <div>item content 3</div>
      <div>item content 4</div>
      <div>item content 5</div>
      <div>item content 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 2">
      <div>item 1</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 3</div>
      <div>item 4</div>
      <div>item 5</div>
      <div>item 6</div>
      <div>item 7</div>
      <div>item 8</div>
      <div>item 9</div>
      <div>item 10</div>
      <div>item 11</div>
      <div>item 12</div>
      <div>item 13</div>
      <div>item 14</div>
      <div>item 15</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with grid layout. but it seems perfect with grid layout. I try to set container's height from 200px to 700px to see the result. It's better to move all the blank to bottom rather than divide them into two parts equally.

Comment: Good and very easy solution.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right then you want this. If not then can you please explain bit more in comment section.

```css
.flex-container {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #dadfe3;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/*.flex-item:first-child {
    min-height: 50%;
}*/

.flex-item {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 20px;
  min-height: 0;
}

.flex-item div {
  margin: 4px 0;
  background-color: #f0f9ff;
  color: #2f88ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>Example 1</h2>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 1">
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 2">
    </div>
  </div>
  

  <h2>Example 2</h2>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 2">
      <div>item 1</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 1">
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

  <h2>Example 3</h2>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 2">
      <div>item 1</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 1">
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
      <div>item content 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

  <h2>Example 4</h2>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 2">
      <div>item 1</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <input type="text" placeholder="filter 1">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Example 2 is great, max-height: 50% is smart. But for example 1, please see my updated question. When the total height of the flex items is less than container's height, I want them to display completely without scrollbar, while the max-height: 50% is not great.

Comment: can you share screenshot or img so that, i can understand properly

Comment: There are two flex items, you are saying if the flex items height is less than the outer container height then it will show in full container. If it, then where will the second flex item go??

Comment: I stick a image link to the question.

Comment: Hey, i guess it's done. please have a look now and do let me know

Comment: Hi bro, I swap positions of two flex items in example 3, and it appear scrollbar again.

Comment: After removing it, flex items in example2 will be different.

Comment: That's all we can do with flex. if still not gives sol. to your answer then skip flex and go ahead with grid as it's solves your problem

Comment: Haha, the question is originally exploratory. Since I am new here, I cannot vote for you. Thank you anyway